# Trying to load Emoji plugin while using CDN version of CKeditor... CORS issue

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm loading the latest (4.10.0) ver of ckeditor via CDN along with a custom config:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/loadCustomConfig.js"></script>
```

and in `loadCustomConfig.js` :

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins='mentions,emoji';
```

and I'm getting

> Failed to load https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.10.0/full-all/plugins/emoji/emoji.json?t=I63C: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://' is therefore not allowed access.

When I remove emoji from the extra plugins config everything loads fine.  I can even set up mentions using CKEDITOR.config.mentions = [];

at first I thought I need to set the dependencies but 'mentions' works...

any ideas?  is this a current bug or am I just missing something?

Comment: tell the CDN to add cors to JSON resources, it's for public consumption after all...

Comment: this was the issue!  thanks!  If you want to answer this issue I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @dandavis this was an issue on CDN side and was fixed in [#2364](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/2364) a while ago.